# EntityType 'UserLogins' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, identity, ef-database-first, database-first

I'm trying to map my ASP.NET identity classes to my database tables but I get a ModelValidationException that says

*"TestJam.UserLogins: : EntityType 'UserLogins' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
UserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'UserLogins' is based on type 'UserLogins' that has no keys defined."*

This is my code:

```
public class TJUserRoles : IdentityUserRole<long> { }

public class TJRoles : IdentityRole<long, TJUserRoles>, Services.IBaseProperties<long>
{
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
    public long ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}

public class TJUserClaims : IdentityUserClaim<long> { }

public class TJUserLogins : IdentityUserLogin<long> { }

public class TJDbContext : IdentityDbContext<TJUsers, TJRoles, long, TJUserLogins, TJUserRoles, TJUserClaims>
{
    public TJDbContext() : base("name=TestJamMilkyWayIdentity")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public static TJDbContext Create()
    {
        return new TJDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TJUserLogins>().Map(c =>
        {
            c.ToTable("UserLogins");
            c.Properties(p => new
            {
                p.UserId,
                p.LoginProvider,
                p.ProviderKey
            });
        }).HasKey(p => new { p.UserId, p.LoginProvider, p.ProviderKey });
```

I tried to map in different orders, but nothing changed.
The

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<TJUsers>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TJRoles>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TJUserRoles>().HasKey(k => new { k.UserId, k.RoleId }).ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<TJUserClaims>().HasKey(k => new { k.Id }).ToTable("UserClaims");

        //modelBuilder.Entity<TJUsers>().HasMany(c => c.Logins).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<TJUsers>().HasMany(c => c.Claims).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<TJUsers>().HasMany(c => c.Roles).WithRequired().HasForeignKey(c => c.UserId);


        modelBuilder.Entity<TJUsers>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TJRoles>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        modelBuilder.Entity<TJUserClaims>().Property(r => r.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
        //modelBuilder.Entity<TJUserLogins>().Property(r => r.UserId).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
    public virtual DbSet<ComplexQuestions> ComplexQuestions { get; set; }
    ....
}

public class TJUserStore : 
    UserStore<TJUsers, TJRoles, long, TJUserLogins, TJUserRoles, TJUserClaims>, 
    IUserStore<TJUsers, long>, 
    IDisposable
{
    public TJUserStore(TJDbContext context) : base(context) { }
}
```

My Table's code in the Database is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserLogins](
    [LoginProvider] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [ProviderKey] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_UserLogins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [LoginProvider] ASC,
    [ProviderKey] ASC,
    [UserId] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserLogins]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.UserLogins_dbo.Users_UserId] FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([Id])
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO
```

Any idea why is this happening?

**Update**

```
    public class TJUsers : IdentityUser<long, TJUserLogins, TJUserRoles, TJUserClaims>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsBlocked { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(TJUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I set up a scratch project and it works okay as a new database.

Can you confirm your `TJUsers` class implements public class `<long,TJUserLogins,TJUserRoles, TJUserClaims>`

Comment: Yes, it does. It's inherited from IdentityUser